# Encode video frame by frame using FFmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, webrtc

I'm trying to encode a WebRTC video. WebRTC provides this method

```
@Override
public void onFrame(VideoFrame frame){
   //FFmpeg command
}
```

Each VideoFrame is **YUV420** and provides information about rotation(integer), timestamp(long), width and height(https://github.com/webrtc-uwp/webrtc/blob/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/VideoFrame.java).

Is it possible to use the above event-method to encode the Video using FFmpeg?

Obviously, video frames would be provided dynamically maybe that's an issue.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Search for “ffmpeg tutorial” or “Libav tutorial” on google. This s a well documented thing to do.

Comment: @szatmary What section do I need to use as reference? Because one thing is to encode a ready video and another is to encode frame by frame video in real time.

Comment: `Because one thing is to encode a ready video and another is to encode frame by frame video in real time.` Which one of those things are you trying to do? looking at the function in the question, you appear to be receiving frames, not full videos.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to encode a video frame by frame while most guides provide information on how to encode a full video

Comment: I typed "libav tutorial" into google, and this was the first hit: https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial#learn-ffmpeg-libav-the-hard-way